# Communicate username in activation email

Tags: django, django-registration

Using Django-Registration-Redux here. The activation email with a link is being send perfectly and I've adjusted the template for the email. 
But I'm wondering if someone can give an example code of how to communicate the Username they just created in this email. {{}} and what settings to adjust.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us the code that you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user` variable is available in the context of the activation email template.  So to output username just add this code: `{{ user.username }}`.